# C# - Arranging DataTable into a "|" Delimited Format With Potential Different Number Of Columns Per Record

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I have imported the result set of a SQL query into a datatable like this:

http://postimg.org/image/rg2eld2wt/

Is there a way to write a line to a text file so that the code column is transposed into a single row arranged like this depending on number of different values in the column?

1|bob|johnson|9/4/1989|1|2|3|4|5|6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the LINQ GroupBy statement.

That is,

```
var lines = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => //grouping Selector
       new { id = row.id, 
       , firstName = row.firstName
       , lastName = row.lastName
       , dob = row.dob
   }, (key, rows) => //result selector
       (key.id + "|" 
         + key.firstname + "|" 
         + key.firstname + "|" 
         + key.dob + "|" 
         + string.Join("|", rows.Select(codeRow => codeRow.code))
    )
);
```

if using untyped datatables, replace the row.foo with row["foo"].

This will give you an IEnumerable full of the rows of the file you desire.  Just write that out to the file.

I obviously havent' tested or even compiled this, but it's a rough sketch of how you can group things in Linq.